# Flex letters on my golf iron shaft

Tags: equipment, terminology, golf

My iron shaft has 2 letters S and R on it. As per my understanding S stands for “Stiff” flex and R is for “Regular” flex and only one letter is suppose to represent flex of a shaft. Why does my iron shaft have 2 letters and what could it mean?
[image: golf driver shaft]

Comment: It's a regular flex. Das S-like thing could as well be a part of the brand. Everything can be read from the right, except for that one. I'm not really sure, though.

Comment: I had the same thought but could not find a single explanation online hence ended up asking the question here. Perhaps there is a certain way manufacturers place flex alphabets on the shafts.